# PHP array input to database

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array passed from my angular to PHP

```
0 => 
array (size=10)
  'id' => string '3' (length=1)
  'vendor' => 
    array (size=1)
      'selected' => 
        array (size=2)
          'vendor' => 'A'
          'id' => '5'
1 => 
array (size=10)
  'id' => string '4' (length=1)
  'vendor' => 
    array (size=1)
      'selected' => 
        array (size=2)
          'vendor' => 'B'
          'id' => '7'
2 => 
array (size=10)
  'id' => string '5' (length=1)
  'vendor' => 
    array (size=1)
      'selected' => 
        array (size=2)
          'vendor' => 'B'
          'id' => '7'
```

What I want to do is sort the array data based on the vendor_id and then insert it into my database. So, by given above data, vendor A has 1 Item, and vendor B has 2 items

After browsed the internet for a quite a while, I found out that I can use following code

```
 if(count($products) > 0){
      foreach($products as $data){
          $input[$data['vendor']['selected']['id']][] = $data;
      }
 }
```

and the new created input array will be like

```
5 => 
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=10)
      'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'vendor' => 
        array (size=1)
          ...
7 => 
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=10)
      'id' => string '4' (length=1)
      'vendor' => 
        array (size=1)
          ...
  1 => 
    array (size=10)
      'id' => string '5' (length=1)
      'vendor' => 
        array (size=1)
          ...
```

And then I loop the input array so I can insert data into my db

```
    //Sample data
    $i = 0;
    foreach($input as $d){
        $param = array(
            "po_number"     => $purchase_number
            "grand_total"   => $d[$i]['total_price']
        );
        $this->_model->add($param); // add into the purchase order table
        $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();

        $products_array[] = array(
           "purchase_order_id" => $insert_id,            
        );

        foreach($products_array as $prod){
            $this->_detail_model->add($prod); // add into the purchase order detail table
        }
    }
```

However, I found out that above code is not working properly. By given above array example, Vendor with 1 item, will be inserted into db twice, while vendor with 2 items, will only be inserted once. I don't know what is wrong, but I feel that the foreach $input array looping somehow is lacking of something. Can somebody help me what to do?

Basically I want to do a purchase order and purchase order detail. by given above example, there would be 2 purchase orders, with 1 purchase order and 1 purchase order detail, and 1 purchase order with 2 purchase order details

Thank you :)